# DIV move up when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I've been trying to get a DIV to move up when using the scroll on browser to move down, but I can't find a solution which works.

More specifically, for example if I fill a DIV with images, I want these images to scroll upwards when I scroll the browser window scrollbar downwards. So as you move longer down the page, the DIV moves upwards and shows more images.

Could you give me some suggestions how to receive such an effect?

Comment: What is the behavior you are seeing right now? The reason I ask is this. By default div's behave the way you expect it to behave. It looks like some style is being applied to the div which may be causing it to behave otherwise. One thing I recommend is that you actually inspect the element (in chrome/firefox) and see what exact style is being applied to the div. Also fiddle around by applying the styles overflow:auto and height:100% to the div if not already applied.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){            
    $("#scrollingDiv").stop().animate({ "marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 30) + "px"}, "slow"); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

What I'm trying to create is something alike the code you suggested. Except that it moves the opposite direction of the way you scroll, so if you scroll up, the div / box scrolls down.

Answer (score 1):

I don't entirely follow what you are trying to do with the `<div>` content, but there is an easy way to detect page scrolling with jQuery:

```
$.scroll(function() {
    alert('Scroll position: ' + $('html').scrollTop());
});
```

From there, you can position whatever you want, however you want, using this value `$('html').scrollTop()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding but, are you trying to keep your DIV in a fixed position regardless of how far the user scrolls down the page?

If so there's a style for that:

```
position:fixed
```

Comment: The thing is, a DIV on a page will move up when a user scrolls down. That's the normal behavior.