# <DIV> move down a page when scrolling

Tags: html, scroll, move

I need to make a div scroll when the page scrolls. Specifically, the div contains an iframe and when the user scrolls down the page I want them to be able to see the entire iframe, instead of it scrolling off the screen. I looked at this: [DIV move up when scrolling down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140259/div-move-up-when-scrolling-down), but it doesn't work for me, although I could be using it incorrectly - I just added it to my .js file. How can I do this? Thank you.

Here is the code I added to my .js file:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){            
    $("#scrollingDiv").stop().animate({ "marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 30) + "px"}, "slow"); 
});
```

Comment: Not sure have you ever heard of CSS `position: sticky`? Other then that you need to make [mre] of your problematic code.

Comment: use `position: fixed` or `position:sticky`  and your problem has already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576342/css-to-keep-element-at-fixed-position-on-screen

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about "sticky." It's doing most of the work I need it to do. I'll work with it. It does not keep the div "stuck" unless there is something underneath it. I'm actually looking to keep it "stuck" relative to an image on its left side, but "sticky" shows me what I need. Thanks again.